# BSC Op Code Costs

Tags: gas, opcode, binance

Where can I find the current cost of gas for each OP Code on the Binance Smart Chain?  Is the gas per opcode always going to be the same as Ethereum?  I'm specfically trying to figure out how much gas it's going to cost me to iterate an array of 1000 elements.

Answer (score 1):

> Where can I find the current cost of gas for each OP Code on the Binance Smart Chain?

The BSC Geth client fork ([here](https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc)) has the list of opcodes and associated gas costs in [`protocol_params.go`](https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc/blob/master/params/protocol_params.go).

> Is the gas per opcode always going to be the same as Ethereum?

Not necessarily. The file I've pointed to above *does* appear to have been changed for use in BSC, specifically with regards to the gas costs associated with their Parlia Proof-of-Staked-Authority consensus engine.

> I'm specfically trying to figure out how much gas it's going to cost me to iterate an array of 1000 elements.

Rather than manually looking at opcodes, a better way to do this is to run the transaction in Remix, and then check the debug for the associated gas costs.